# Get id from input field using data-target and update class on targeted id in React JS 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hook-form

I am trying to update a Show class on the basis of clicked input field. I am getting id from the data-target attribute which I have placed in the input field and add/remove show class on the targeted id. I have already defined the Id in the span tag  . I am on initial state of react js I am not familier with the all hooks.

Here is the code of the react componant

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ContactUs = () => {
    const [userValue, setName] = useState({
        fname: "",
        lname: "",
        email: "",
    });

    const formFill = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const name = event.target.name;

        setName((defaultValues) => {
            if (name === "fname") {
                return {
                    fname: value,
                    lname: defaultValues.lname,
                }
            } else if (name === "lname") {
                return {
                    fname: defaultValues.fname,
                    lname: value,
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }

    //Add and remove show class
    const [targetedID, setIDname] = useState();
    const toggleClass = (event) => {
        const ID = event.target.getAttribute("data-target");
        setIDname(ID);
        const targetid = document.getElementById(targetedID);
        if(targetid === ID){
            targetid.classList.add("show");
        }else{
            targetid.classList.remove("show");
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form action="" className="bg-white rounded-2 p-5 col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <h1 className="h6 fw-semibold mb-3">Contact Form</h1>
                <div className="form-group mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">First Name </label>
                    <div className="position-relative">
                        <span className="tooltip" id="fnameId">{userValue.fname}</span>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fname" value={userValue.fname} onChange={formFill} onClick={toggleClass} placeholder="First Name" data-target="#fnameId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div className="position-relative">
                        <span className="tooltip" id="lnameId">{userValue.lname}</span>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lname" value={userValue.lname} onChange={formFill} onClick={toggleClass} placeholder="Last Name" data-target="#lnameId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Email</label>
                    <div className="position-relative">
                        <span className="tooltip" id="lnameId">{userValue.email}</span>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="email" value={userValue.email} onChange={formFill} onClick={toggleClass} placeholder="example@domain.com" data-target="#emailId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mb-4">
                    <button type="buttom" className="btn btn-danger btn-md text-uppercase fw-semibold">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default ContactUs;
```